# How to orchestrate spring batch jobs without kubernetes

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-batch

We have developed some spring batch jobs. I understand Spring Cloud Data Flow is the recommended solution to orchestrate spring batch jobs and it requires platforms such as Cloud Foundry and Kubernetes. However, our company does not allow these platforms. We use docker containers on azure. Azure kubernetes is also not an option. What are the other solutions for orchestration?